# How to fix onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=8 error inside BluetoothGATT?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, google-pixel

Hi I am working on BLE connection with BluetoothAdapter I have found that my prob gets disconnect after some hours in Android O+ devices.
After analysing Log file BluetoothGATT is returning onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=8 status. How do I solve this problem?Is this problem is related to BLE device or android API level issue is there?

> BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=8 device
>   2019-02-15 11:06:28.614 1569-1569/E/ManagerActivity: Receiving broadcast update
>   2019-02-15 11:06:28.614 1569-1569//ManagerActivity: ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED

bug report from developer option I have found 'reason Remote user terminated connection'

Comment: Code 22 means that Android chose to disconnect the device. You need to add more info in order to be able to determine the cause. For example, do you have an app running that keeps the connection open?

Comment: App is running continuously but in google pixel after some hours it goes disconnected with same status error.

Comment: We have also tried to reconnect the BLE in such condition but failed to do so, as it was completely off at that time. It was not in advertising mode.

Comment: Do you get the callback onConnectionStateChange in your app?

Comment: Yes, it is printing Log statement from the same `if (DBG) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClientConnectionState() - status=" + status
                                + " clientIf=" + clientIf + " device=" + address);
                    }`

Comment: here due to disconnection BLE device stops advertising

Comment: Emil I have stuck with this issue from one month and this problem is unidentified why BLE device is disconnecting. Is it Device issue or OS issue?

Comment: You could try "Take bug report" in Android developer settings. Then read the big text log file to see if you can see any reason why it disconnects. Also which phones does this problem happen on?

Comment: I have tried on Google Pixel 1 Android version 9 and BLE device gets disconnect after every 18 hours 20 minutes with the same status i.e. 22