# Android closes BLE connection (status=22) after some hours

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

This is certainly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859953/how-to-fix-onclientconnectionstate-status-22-clientif-8-error-inside-bluetoo). I'd have left a comment there but I'm still too young here to do so. :)
I have a Android app (on many different devices and different Android versions) that connects to a custom device based on a STM32WB55 device. I leave the connection opened, just a battery level sent every minute, and it ends with a "status = 22" on the Android side after some hours. It can be more than a day but usually around 18h. With a BLE Sniffer I can see the Master (Android) stops with no apparent reason to send "EmptyPDU" packets. Could it be Android that decides it can/must wipe out the app for an unknown reason (GC?)?

I was expecting the connection to stay alive as far as the embedded side doesn't close it explicitly.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested "Take bug report" in Android developer settings?

Comment: I haven't. Since I'm not always in front of the tablet when that occurs, it can last some hours before I get it. I don't know if the tool can pick informations that old, but I confess I never used it.

Comment: I'm not sure either, it was just the suggestion from last time to figure out why the android system decided to kill the connection... Maybe it is some energy saving behaviour